# How to declare Cocoa classes which WILL be available later?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins

First I have to say that I am nowhere near a good programmer in Objective-C.

My problem is that I want to develop a plugin (which is ultimately a dylib in this context) declaring some Cocoa classes. This plugin would be loaded first so other plugins would be able to use the classes already declared in the ObjC runtime.

Unfortunately, I always get errors when trying to compile other plugins because some classes are missing. I thought that providing the .h files or @class would be enough but no.

How can I tell the compiler that some classes will be available from the Runtime when it needs it ?

Comment: Can you share the specific errors you're getting during compilation? Usually, including the headers or forward-declaring classes with `@class` _is_ the way to inform the compiler of this, so the errors would be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Error is: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_myClass for every class I defined. The main .h file imports all the headers for the objc classes and the main .m file adds @class for each class.

Comment: When you say "main `.h`" and "main `.m`", is that for your plugin, or for the main executable itself? Because the main executable won't be able to reference classes from your plugin explicitly without being directly linked to them; i.e., if you refer to a class by name, the linker expects the class to exist at link time or else you'll get this exact failure. (Unless you explicitly inform it using something like the `BUNDLE_LOADER` to let it know where the classes _will_ be.)

Comment: In general, when you have a plugin architecture like this, you typically need to be much more dynamic than you might otherwise be used to. You typically need to declare a shared interface of some variety (e.g. a protocol) that classes will conform to, and have plugins vend opaque objects conforming to that interface. But you typically can't rely on _specific_ classes and types because they simply won't exist when your executable launches. So, e.g., if your main executable loads a plugin, have the plugin return some object that the executable knows how to interface with (but not know the type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually easy as I just needed to weak-link against the dynamic library inside the first plugin.

Even though the dylib is actually embedded in a zip archive, the main application loads it in memory and make it available to the other plugins.

Thanks everyone for your messages.

Answer (score 1):

If your classes defined in other binary, you need to specify `BUNDLE_LOADER` key in build settings, so linker could find those dependent symbols. (Note: .h files are needed only for compiler to find interface declarations).

[image: demo]

Comment: It is not necessary in my particular case because symbols are resolved at runtime by each plugin. But that is a very good point, thank you.